# Disabled options in react dropdown depending on specific conditions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dropdown

I am currently building a dropdown component in react. It already works fine - I now would like to have some options disabled only when a specific condition occurs. In this case I have two dropdowns which work as a filter system. The first is a "from"-filter and the second a "to"-filter. If you select an option in the "from"-dropdown, I'd like the "to"-dropdown to disable the selected and all previous options.

This is my code:

```
import {
  Dropdown,
  IDropdownStyles,
  IDropdownOption,
} from "@fluentui/react";    

interface DropdownProps {
  options: IDropdownOption[],
  placeholder: string,
  setDropdown: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}

const dropwdownStyles: Partial<IDropdownStyles> = {
  dropdown: { width: 300 },
};

export const DropdownId = (props: DropdownProps) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <Dropdown
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        options={props.options}
        styles={dropwdownStyles}
        onChange={(e, options) => {
          props.setDropdown(`${options?.key}`)
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Implementing the dropdown in index.tsx:

```
    <Container>
                      <DropdownId options={apiTagsResponse.map(tag => ({ text: tag, key: tag }))} setDropdown={setStartObjectId} placeholder="Set Start Tag" />
                    </Container>
                    <Container>to</Container>
                    <Container>
                      <DropdownId options={apiTagsResponse.map(tag => ({ text: tag, key: tag }))} setDropdown={setEndObjectId} placeholder="Set End Tag" />
                    </Container>
                    <Container>
                      <DropdownApplyFilterButton onClick={() => setButtonClicked(true)} />
                    </Container>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Would you mind adding the full props so we can see what you are actually doing?